# How to execute a script from custom NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package

I have created a custom NPM package which (at the moment) does contain a script which I want to execute from within another project.

This is how my package looks like:

**myScript.js**

```
console.log("The script has been executed!");
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/my-script",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "main": "./src/myScript.js",
  "files": ["src/*"],
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node src/myScriptjs"
  }
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
src/
 - myScript.js
.gitignore
package.json
```

I have successfully added the package to my other project as a *dev-dependency* and now I would like to do something like:

```
yarn myscript
```

where the corresponding script in the project's `package.json` would be something like:

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "node point/to/myscript.js"
}
```

*Just to clarify: I would like to avoid to write:*

```
"myscript": "node node_modules/@myscope/my-script/src/myscript.js"
```

*Instead I would like to have something like:*

```
"myscript": "node @myscope/my-script myscript.js"
```

I believe that something like the above is possible if the script is added to the `node_modules/.bin` folder. How would I get my script into there? Or is there any other way to make my script executable other than referring to the path in `node_modules`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
npm run-script <custom_script_name>
```

or

```
npm run <custom_script_name>
```

Kindly, don't forget to check the Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this answer. I know how to run scripts from a `package.json`, the question was how would I traget my custom script, which is located at `node_modules/@myscope/my-script/myscript.js` without referring to the entire folder?

Comment: I see. I'll be back after searching for it.